# Destructuring an Object fields and Calculating the Sum in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I am having trouble figuring out how to destructure and add the total sum of an object with fields. Previously we bad separate objects in an object array. Now they are summed in 1 object and it looks like this:

```
{
  "3" {
   petIds:{
    "113": {"estimatedEats": 10, "owners": {"female":{"kids":1, "adult":2, "senior":10}}, "male":{"kids":1, "adult":2, "senior":10}}
     "9": {"estimatedEats": 1, owners: {…}}}

  "6":{
   petIds:{
     "113": {"estimatedEats": 5, "owners": {…}}
     "9": {"estimatedEats": 6, "owners": {…}}
     "1": {"estimatedEats": 7, "owners": {…}}}
  }
```

Previously I could map object arrays. I want to end up with an object array that looks like this:

```
[{petIds:113, "estimatedEats":15, "owners": (sum of owner description)}...]
```

Is there a way where I could convert each field to an object array? I think it would be easier for me to do that and map the array.

Comment: "convert each field to an object array" so, how? There are many ways to do what you're describing, with various results.

Comment: Please show exactly what is supposed to go in the "owners" field of the sum.

Comment: An object is like an associative array in fact.

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started:

```
var x = {
  3:{
   petIds:{
    113: {estimatedEats: 10, owners: {}},
     9: {estimatedEats: 1, owners: {}}
   }
  },
  6:{
   petIds:{
     113: {"estimatedEats": 5, "owners": {}},
     9: {"estimatedEats": 6, "owners": {}},
     1: {"estimatedEats": 7, "owners": {}}
   }
  }
};

var pets = [];
Object.keys(x).forEach(function(key) {
    var y = x[key];
    Object.keys(y).forEach(function(objKey) {
        if(objKey === 'petIds'){
          var z = y[objKey];
          Object.keys(z).forEach(function(petKey) {
            var pet = Object.assign({},z[petKey]);
            pet.id = parseInt(petKey);
            pets.push(pet);
          });
        };
    });
});

var sumPets = [];

pets.forEach(function(p){
  var idx = sumPets.findIndex(function(i){
    return i.id === p.id;
  });

  if(idx < 0){
    sumPets.push(p);
  } else {
    sumPets[idx].estimatedEats = sumPets[idx].estimatedEats + p.estimatedEats;
  }
});

console.log(sumPets);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you try to achieve, but I'll do my best to answer :)

> Is there a way where I could convert each field to an object array? I think it would be easier for me to do that and map the array.

`Object.values` creates an array with all values of an object. Is that what you were looking for?

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/a-morn/pen/KOQvVv) where I sum `estimatedEats` using the `Object` and `Array` methods. I think you should be able to sum up the other properties too based on this.

```js
const data = {
  3: {
    petIds: {
      113: {
        estimatedEats: 10,
        owners: { female: { kids: 1, adult: 2, senior: 10 } },
        male: { kids: 1, adult: 2, senior: 10 }
      },
      1: {
        estimatedEats: 120,
        owners: { female: { kids: 1, adult: 2, senior: 10 } },
        male: { kids: 1, adult: 2, senior: 10 }
      }
    }
  },
  6: {
    petIds: {
      113: {
        estimatedEats: 5,
        owners: { female: { kids: 1, adult: 2, senior: 10 } },
        male: { kids: 1, adult: 2, senior: 10 }
      },
      1: {
        estimatedEats: 5,
        owners: { female: { kids: 1, adult: 2, senior: 10 } },
        male: { kids: 1, adult: 2, senior: 10 }
      }
    }
  }
};

const groupedById = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, { petIds }) => {
  Object.entries(petIds).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key].push(value);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

const summedUp = Object.entries(groupedById).map(
  ([key, value]) =>
    value.reduce(
      (acc, row) => {
        acc.estimatedEats += row.estimatedEats;
        return acc;
      },
      { estimatedEats: 0, petIds: key }
    ),
  []
);

console.log("Result:", summedUp);
```

Update: pasted the code into my answer too.